# How to convert Buffered Image to PlayN Image?

Tags: playn

I came across an interface which transforms java buffered images to playN images

http://code.google.com/p/playn/source/browse/java/src/playn/java/JavaBitmapTransformer.java?spec=svn16f0f5b72f732f47b05c2857e1b64bc6bbe5c14f&r=16f0f5b72f732f47b05c2857e1b64bc6bbe5c14f.

But i was not able to figure out. Can any one know how to use it exactly?.....

Thanks in advance...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use it directly in a cross-platform way.

This interface does not transform a `BufferedImage` to a PlayN image. It transforms one `BufferedImage` into another `BufferedImage`. This new `BufferedImage` will subsequently be used to create a PlayN image in the Java platform specific code of PlayN.

This interface is used under the hood to support the [transform method](http://docs.playn.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/playn/core/Image.html#transform%28playn.core.Image.BitmapTransformer%29) in `Image`.

Comment: Yes you are right. We can't convert a buffered Image to playN Image. We need to save those under resource directory and use them by calling PlayN.assets().getImage() method. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @thomasbroad : Thanks for this post. So what do you think we can do for transforming an Image in some other platform like Android, to a PlayN Image?